# How do I get a list of SQL Servers available on my network?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying this but I'm not sure how to proceed. Can you give me a hand?

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();

foreach (var row in table.Rows)
{
     foreach (var column in table.Columns)
     {
          ddlPublisherServer.Items.Add(???);
     }
}
```

Where ??? = SQL Server Name.

How would I go about extracting the sql server name from the table?

I'm working in ASP .NET with C#.

Comment: Idk, put a break point there and look at that column names and values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if wanted to see all available information, you can iterate over the columns available:

```
DataTable dt = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}: {1}", col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Which would show something like:

```
ServerName     : COMPUTER1
InstanceName   : SQLEXPRESS
IsClustered    : No
Version        : 9.00.4035.00
```

So, to answer your question:

```
ddlPublisherServer.Items.Add(row[table.Columns["ServerName"]]);
```

Full Code:

```
DataTable table = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
foreach (DataRow server in table.Rows)
{
  ddlPublisherServer.Items.Add(server[table.Columns["ServerName"]].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it keeps saying "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'" do you know why?

Comment: @Testifier: Forgot it wants a `DataColumn` and not an index. Just need to pass the column you're requesting (in this case, `table.Columns["ServerName"]`).

Comment: @Testifier: It's probably a compile-time detection problem. Instead of using `var` forcibly declare them as `DataTable` and `DataRow` and try again (I've updated my answer with what I mentioned). **EDIT** Also, I assume `ddlPublisherServer` is `IEnumerable<String>`? Make sure you call `ToString()` on the `server[]` result.

Comment: ahhh you missed the "toString" at the end. trying this now.