# Listing all available servers in network

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, winforms

I have a Windows Form application that I made in C#. It is connected to a SQL Server database that is located on my computer (Full version of SQL Server 2012). I need to move this application to several different client's computers. The database that the clients will use will have all of the same fields as the one I am testing with, and it will be located on their computer/server.

I decided to make a window open when the application launches that will give a list of available servers, databases and tables. When the form launches, a list of servers will populate a dropdown. When they choose a server, a list of databases will be shown in the next dropdown. When they choose a database, a list of tables will be show in the last dropdown. When the user clicks the `Log In` button, it will change the connection string in the `App.config` file.

What I have somewhat works, but it seems as though the server list is incomplete

```
public initializationForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataTable table = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
    foreach (DataRow server in table.Rows)
    {
        if (!this.serverComboBox.Items.Contains(server[table.Columns["ServerName"]].ToString()))
        {
            this.serverComboBox.Items.Add(server[table.Columns["ServerName"]].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to my list of networks in the File Explorer, there are 15 servers listed. But when I run this, only 3 are displayed. I also tried to install this on a development server that uses SQL Server 2012 Express. The server name on the development server is `SOMESERVER\SQLEXPRESS`, but this code only displays `SOMESERVER`.

How can I get ALL of the servers shown in the File Explorer, and how can I get it to display the full server name? Thanks for the help!

---

Resources I used:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

[How do I get a list of SQL Servers available on my network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462120/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-sql-servers-available-on-my-network)

Comment: The SQL Browser service needs to be running on those target machines for the instances to be found while enumerating.

Comment: I'm trying to make moving this form to clients computers as automatic as possible (So I don't have to follow a list of 15 steps to move it). Is there any way to do this in C#? Or do I always have to manually turn this service on? I also just ran the `SQL Browser Service`, and there is no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never get ALL SQL servers. Some are not configured to broadcast their existence. Some could be listening on non-standard ports. Furthermore, SQL server broadcasts are literally network broadcasts, so that will not (usually) propogate through routers. Also, you can be limited by security -- i.e., you must have permission to browser SQL servers.

So, you at best can use this to find some servers. You will still need the ability for clients to configure their server by entering server name, and possible logic credentials, alternate port / initial catalog, etc.

I have also observed that this browsing process can be frustratingly slow in some environments -- can't tell you why, never debugged this.

ADDED

Forgot to mention, if you took at the table, there is a column for ServerName (that you use), there is also a column for InstanceName that will give you servnamename\instance that you asked about.

Comment: `server[table.Columns["InstanceName"]].ToString()` doesn't give me the instance name for some readon. It just returns a blank string